# find().populate() vs find().find() in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I was wondering, what is the difference between using populate and using the find methods in a mongoose ORM.

Let's say I have two models. 1. User and 2.Post

```
mongoose.model('User', mongoose.Schema({
user : {type: String},
posts : [type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'Post'}]
}))
```

and the Post model

```
mongoose.model('Post', mongoose.Schema({
user : {type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
title : {type: String},
body : {type:String}
}))
```

I want to generate **all** the **posts** by an **User**.
I can do either:

```
User.findById({_id:req._id}).then(currentUser => Post.find({user._id: currentUser}) ........
```

Or:

```
User.findById({_id:req._id}).populate('posts')
```

Which one is the correct way? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose populate is not magic, as it’s still a client side look up vs $lookup, which is a server side lookup.

For a single findById query you may not see any benefits by comparing the 2 statements.

You can see the benefits of .populate when you use query such as find().populate() where you more than one record is returned.